# Unwanted buttons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jsplitpane

Can anyone tell me please why do buttons appear in the bottom panels and how can I get rid of them?

I meant to create three different panels with three different colors and I ended up with one color and two buttons.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;


public class Mywindow extends JFrame {

public Mywindow() {
    setTitle("My window");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(500, 500);

    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
    rightPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    JSplitPane sp=new JSplitPane();
    JSplitPane sp2=new JSplitPane();

    sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, centerPanel, sp);
    sp2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, rightPanel);

    add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Mywindow();
    }    
}
```

Comment: is this the real code? do you have a screen shot?

Comment: here you are https://i.imgur.com/frx9pvi.png

Comment: do you use an ide? try to recompile/clean the code and run it again

Comment: `sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, centerPanel, sp);` Why add the `JScrollPane` to itself? What is that supposed to achieve? *"so I should start mansplaining"* No, you should provide a clear problem statement and code to show your efforts or demonstrate the problem. It seems you did both, but (I'm guessing) got caught out by the SO's software algorithms. Feel free to add more words when that happens, but note that if you throw in words like 'mansplainng', it will earn an automatic down vote from me.

Comment: I apologize I meant no offence, and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
JSplitPane sp=new JSplitPane();
JSplitPane sp2=new JSplitPane();

//adding a split pane to itself will bring no good
sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, centerPanel, sp); 
sp2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, rightPanel);
```

With this:

```
JSplitPane sp2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, rightPanel);
JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, centerPanel, sp2);
```

To see this:

[image]